# Airflow python start date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using airflow start date:

```
from airflow.utils import dates

...

"start_date": dates.days_ago(3)
```

which is coming out to be:
2020-11-14 00:00:00+00:00

I want the date in utc to be of format 2020-11-14 00:00:00

Also want to add the timedelta(minutes=5) to 2020-11-14 00:00:00

How to do it using python(airflow)

Answer (score 1):

First let me point that dynamic date for `start_date` is [not recommended](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date):

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially
> datetime.now() as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered
> once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get
> to an hour after now as now() moves along.

Second I'm puzzled with why it's important to you if it's datetime or pendulum.
The `start_date` and `interval` are used for the scheduler to do it's magic. So you need to provide them according to the required spec.

You didn't write any information about what you really want to do. I would assume that what you really are after is how you leverage the `start_date` to be used in your tasks. For that you can get it in whatever type you wish. Airflow provides some [Macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html) of pendulum type.

Note that you can get the required format for your tasks by:

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S') }}"
```

If you want to add delta you can do:

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the ´datetime´ package. It's really easy to use.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: this might work in principal; however, airflow uses `pendulum` internally (see [src](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/settings.py)), so it could be helpful to have a look at that.